# Getting undefined values form filed in js using struts2, jquery and document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, struts

While submiting this form i am getting undefined values in the browser console. did i mistake in the code any where? but i am getting proper values while submiting other forms in same project.

Exact  error img: [image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').on('click','#regSub',function(evt){  
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("executed");
        console.log($('#ss').val());
        console.log(document.getElementById('ss').value);})});
```

```
    <s:div>
        
        <s:form >
        <label>Enter PNR value :
        <input id="ss"></label>
        <s:submit id="regSub" value="Submit"></s:submit>
        </s:form>
        
    </s:div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the exact errors you're getting.

Comment: Just added the error image, Tim.

Comment: After `executed` should be `cancelled` log.

Answer (score 0):

Basic form :

```
<form class="form-acion" action="">
  <input id="ss" type="text" value="">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log($('#ss').val())
  })
})
```

In your case with a defer form:

```
$.when($('form')).then(function(element) {
  element.submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log($('#ss').val())
  })
});
```

More information about jQuery `$.when` and its promises : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. In You're answer, you're clearly stating that, When exactly jQuery should happen like  onsubmit, onclick, onchange. 

But the thing, Which I dont know is, why "$('#ss').val()" is giving value of undefined(empty string) when i type and submit the value in html page.

I tried with your code, it produces the same undefined.

Comment: The reason is you have to set the `value` on your input.